# How to prevent Spark from keeping old data leading to out of memory in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using structured streaming in spark but I'm struggeling to understand the data kept in memory. Currently I'm running Spark 2.4.7 which says ([Structured Streaming Programming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html))

> The key idea in Structured Streaming is to treat a live data stream as a table that is being continuously appended.

Which I understand as that Spark appends all incoming data to an unbounded table, which never gets truncated, i.e. it will keep growing indefinetly.

I understand the concept and why it is good, for example when I want to aggregaet based on event-time I can use `withWatermark`to tell spark which column that is the event-time and then specify how late I want to receive data, and let spark know to throw everything older than that.

However lets say I want to aggregate on something that is not event-time. I have a usecase where each message in kafka contains an array of datapoints. So, I use `explode_outer` to create multiple rows for each message, and for these rows (within the same message) I would like to aggregate based on message-id (getting `max`, `min`, `avg` e.t.c.). **So my question is, will Spark keep all "old" data since that how Structured Streaming work which will lead to OOM-issues? And is the only way to prevent this to add a "fictional" `withWatermark` on for example the time i received the message and include this in my `groupBy`as well?**

And the other usecase, where I do not even want to do a groupBy, I simply want to do some transformation on each message and then pass it along, I only care about the current "batch". **Will spark in that case also keep all old messages forcing me to to a"fictional" `withWatermark` along with a `groupBy` (including message-id in the `groupBy` and taking for example `max` of all columns)?**

I know I can move to the good old DStreams to eliminate my issue and simply handle each message seperatly, but then I loose all the good things about Strucutred Streaming.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to avoid watermarking ?

Comment: DStreams are deprecated.

Comment: @VindhyaG I want to avoid watermarking since I want to process message by message. I explode each message to multiple rows, on which I do a GroupBy on. So I only do groupby isolated on each message.

Comment: I think i get it. So you have single event(which will have a event time field i am guessing) which gets exploded to multiple ones. Is it not possible to add the time field to all the exploded message. Something like  .withcolumn(capturedtimecolumn before explode) to resolve this?

Comment: Yes, thats a correct interpretation. And yes. it's perfectly possible to add event-time to all "eploded rows" (that's actually what I'm doing). But sometimes messages comes in with event-time 6 month old (in extreme cases) and I want to process those messages two, without having a 6 month watermark.

Comment: Then may be have watermark on a column(create a new column before groupby or as soon as you read from the source  and explode ) add current time to that column instead of using the actual event time coming from the event ?

Comment: That ended up being a my solution, but it felt like an ugly hack.

Comment: I Don’t think it is a hack. Essentially it’s like a usual transformation usecase i.e  flow of events(without aggregation ) with  output of every window having no effect or dependency  from events of later windows

Answer (score 0):

Yes watermarking is necessary to bound the result table and to add  event time in groupby.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#handling-late-data-and-watermarking

Any reason why you want to avoid that ?

And watermarking is "strictly" required only if you have aggregation or join to avoid late events being missed in the aggregation/join(and affect the output) but not for events which just needed to transform and flow since output  will not have any effect by late events but if you want very late events to be dropped you might want to add watermarking.  Some links to refer.

https://medium.com/@ivan9miller/spark-streaming-joins-and-watermarks-2cf4f60e276b
https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/watermarking-in-spark-structured-streaming-a1cf94a517ba

Comment: "And watermarking is "strictly" required only if you have aggregation or join to avoid late events being missed" So If i do not have aggregation or join, Spark will automatically drop old messages and not keep them in memory?

Comment: Yes watermarking will drop old messages.Spark doc says  "the engine will maintain state and allow late data to update the state until (max event time seen by the engine - late threshold > T). In other words, late data within the threshold will be aggregated, but data later than the threshold will start getting dropped " https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations-on-event-time . Refer this section

Comment: Note i am pointing to spark 2.3.2 Spark doc but this has not changed in 2.4.7 too